# how to show data having multiple row and columns like grid in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am doing wp7 application in which i need to show data having multiple rows and columns in it.
I want to know if there is any control like grid or table view which can show data having multiple rows and column. Is there any way to show data having multiple rows and columns?

Comment: You want to know if there's a control similar to `Grid` for Windows Phone 7 but you couldn't be bothered to type in [Windows Phone 7 grid](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+phone+7+grid&go=&qs=n&sk=&sc=8-20&form=QBLH) into a search engine? That would've taken you less time than it did to post this question!

Answer (score 2):

use `Grid`.

Here's a blog that seems reasonable : [.Net Framework 3.5: Grid In WPF](http://blogonwpfwcf.blogspot.com/2009/02/grid-in-wpf.html)

Here's the official documentation: [Grid Class (System.Windows.Controls)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx)

And in general, here's a getting started guide to WP7 development: [Create.msdn Windows Phone Development](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/wp7_training_kit)

Cheers